# Mapping database from Neon to Civi

Tags: database

Our organization is considering moving to CiviCRM after many years with Z2Systems Neon CRM and in downloading the MySQL database from Neon we note that there are 10 pages of table in the Neon database and only 4 in the Civi template.  How do we map Neon to Civi?

Answer (score 1):

Another tool that folk who are moving to CiviCRM and Drupal may find interesting is the Drupal module [CiviMigrate](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civimigrate). There is a fairly historic write up of it [here](https://www.fuzion.co.nz/content/migrate-2-civicrm-api-3-civimigrate)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Civi! I'm not aware of an existing mapping template from Neon to Civi, but there are a number of resources for preparing for such a change.  [Sanjay's answer (and Jon G's comment)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/17424/105) provide a good primer here on StackExchange for getting ready for such a move.  The Civi docs also provide an excellent [introduction to importing data into Civi](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/).

Another tool you may find useful is [API CSV Import GUI extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui) if you have data outside the standard import fields.